# JQuery validate on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [JQuery validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate fields in my form which contains a drop down list and other text fields but I can't figure our how to check if the selected item value in the drop down list is > 0 so I was wondering if anyone has an idea how I can check on the selected item value using JQuery validate plugin?

Currently I am using this code to make sure that the drop down list field is required, but not sure how to add the validate selected value code:

```
$( "#contactusform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    country: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

HTML select:

```
<select id="country">
  <option value="0">-Select Country-</option>
  <option value="1">United States</option>
  <option value="2">China</option>
  <option value="3">France</option>
</select>
```

I want to make sure the visitor select any country but not the "-Select Country-" which have value = 0

Thanks for your time

Comment: Why don't you just disable the negative items in the drop-down, sothey can't select them?

Comment: Where is the HTML markup?

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure what do you mean by negative items, but if you are referring to item with value = 0, how I can disable it? Please note that item with value = 0 have text = - Select Country - then countries in the drop down menu start from 1 and up

Comment: @Sparky HTML for the drop down list added to the question

Comment: First `option` element needs to have `value=""` in order for the `required` rule to work.

Comment: Your `select` must also contain a `name` attribute.

Comment: The usual solution is to use `value=""` on the `-Select Country-` option. Then all you have to do is make it required.

Comment: Despite there already being an "accepted" answer, I posted [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19779914/594235) to illustrate @Barmar's point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min` and `max` for this

```
$( "#contactusform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    country: {
      required: true,
      min: 1, //validates minimum value the element has to have
      max:5  // validates the max value
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `required` rule is totally superfluous here because, without a `value=""` on the first `<option>` element, it will never be invoked.

Comment: @Sahil one major problem in this syntax is that it won't work on drop down lists that are loaded dynamically by JQuery as for those drop down lists the HTML source of the page don't physically change so the value of the drop down list is always 1 :( any thoughts how to overcome this problem?

Comment: @Sparky Changing the default value to "" will require some changes in code and the way things are saved in DB so isn't there any work around without having value = "" ?

Comment: @Mchan the only alternative that i see here is that you write your custom method using $.validator.addMethod("methodName",element,param){... } //see validation docs for more info ,  and here check the value using element.val and return false from this method if conditions not met, you might have to use onchange event as well.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your updated OP:

```
$( "#contactusform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        country: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

HTML select:

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="0">-Select Country-</option>
    <option value="1">United States</option>
    <option value="2">China</option>
    <option value="3">France</option>
</select>
```

> *"I want to make sure the visitor select any country but not the "-Select Country-" which have value = 0"*

Two problems here...

1)  Your `<select>` element must have a unique `name` attribute in order for it to be picked up by the jQuery Validate plugin.

2)  Your first `<option>` element must have `value=""` in order for the `required` rule to work:  `<option value="">-Select Country-</option>`

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/cdPs9/**

---

If your first `<option>` element cannot have `value=""` for whatever reason, then use the `min` rule as a workaround.  The `required` rule is not used in this case as it will never be invoked.  I also use the `messages` option to over-ride the default `min` error message.

```
rules: {
    country: {
        min: 1
    }
},
messages: {
    country: "this field is required"
}
```

**Working DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/cdPs9/1/**

Comment: this will work only for the static loaded drop down lists. For dynamically loaded drop down lists (using JQuery) it will not work

Comment: @MChan, dynamically loaded form elements has nothing to do with your question or the accepted answer!

Comment: no it does, as the proposed solution didn't work for me in some cases (which is dynamically loaded drop down lists). Anyway, I have already selected an answer which is correct for the initial question, so you don't need to worry much!

Comment: @MChan, I'm not worried much about anything, but I think you're pretty confused about what you've asked.  Your OP clearly says nothing about dynamically loading anything and the accepted answer will not work any differently on dynamically created elements than mine.  The only difference is that I've removed the superfluous `required` rule... http://jsfiddle.net/cdPs9/1/

Comment: This 10 year old answer helped me with an ASP.NET Core 7 Razor Pages project, which still uses the blasted jQuery Unobtrusive Validation library! Been so long, I forgot how nasty that library was, even back then. I remember you from back when, you were the library's resident expert as I recall... Thanks Sparky!